# How to use numbers present as text with different unit prefixes in calculations

Tags: if-statement, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have data in a spreadsheet describing amount of data transferred over a mobile network: data in one column (over 300 rows) has three possible forms:

```
123,45KB  
123,45MB  
1,23GB
```

How can I transform or use this data in order to sum or do other calculations on numbers properly?

Comment: I believe you misinterpret the problem. If you have the data "123,45KB", "123,45MB", "1,23GB" in cells of a sheet already, then this data is text and not numeric. So "in order to sum them up or do other calculations" a **number** format cannot help. Instead transforming the text data to numeric data is necessary at first.

Comment: You are right. I asumed that I need to format the cells into numbers somehow in order to do calculations, but the final goal - echievable via different methods - is to do a sum (or other calculations) from data present. I have edited the question and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column `A` and there are always two characters as unit ("KB", "MB" or "GB") at the end, then the formula for transforming the data to numeric could be:

```
=--LEFT(A2;LEN(A2)-2)*10^(IF(RIGHT(A2;2)="KB";3;IF(RIGHT(A2;2)="MB";6;IF(RIGHT(A2;2)="GB";9))))
```

Result:

[image]

Put the formula in `B2` and fill downwards as needed.

I suspected the decimal delimiter in your locale is comma. If not, please state what it is.

Also since this site is English, I have used English function names. Maybe you need to translate them into your language version.

If the decimal delimiter in your locale is **not** comma, then you need substituting the comma with your decimal delimiter to get a proper numeric decimal value.

For example if the decimal delimiter is dot, then:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2),",",".")*10^(IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="KB",3,IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="MB",6,IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="GB",9))))
```

Comment: thank you @AxelRichter , but it doesn't work. it gives me #VALUE! error. if i go step by step: `=LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)` produces a valid result, but when i add a `*10` to it, it throws an error. does that mean that what's produced by LEFT is not a number (yet)?

Comment: @Nova deViator: As said, I suspected the decimal delimiter in your locale is comma. If the decimal delimiter in your locale is not comma, then you need substituting the comma with your decimal delimiter. See my supplement.

Comment: I'm thinking about that comma, actually. My default locale on my system is not Slovene, so my system asumes numbers with period as decimal delimiter. But my data is in Slovene format, which uses comma as decimal delimiter. Which means that after first LEFT function I end up with 12,34 but Calc does not see that as a number.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Regarding the problem with decimal delimiter and locale, your alternative solution worked, but also I was able to use your first option by first changing "Locale setting" to Slovenian in Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)*10^(3*MATCH(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)),{"K","M","G"},0))
```

Uses the position of the next to last character in an array to determine the factor.